# How to use regular expressions on an index of a String of array in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am basically trying to find regular expression for a text "TC XX" where XX can be any two digit number. My piece of code is:

```
boolean b = DocArray[RTArrayIndex].matches("/TC \\d{2}/");
```

where DocArray - an array of string which is basically derived from another string separated by `\t`

RTArrayIndex - current index of the DocArray array.

Regular Expression - `/TC \\d{2}/`

The value of string at the current index is "TC 10", but still the value of "b" I am getting is false.

Another index of the array contains the string, "Refer Logs of TC 10" too, but again the value of "b" is false.

Comment: remove '/' from your regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems. First, your regex contains some "/" characters, which it is attempting to match. If you remove both of those, you will have a slightly better regex.

```
boolean b = DocArray[RTArrayIndex].matches("TC \\d{2}");
```

The regex above should evaluate for your first example, but not your second. You need to account for leading and trailing characters. You can do this by using the ".*" symbol. "." is a placeholder for any character at all, "*" means it can be seen any number of times. If you add ".*" to the beginning and end of your pattern, any string that contains the substring "TC \d\d" will match to your regex.

```
boolean b = DocArray[RTArrayIndex].matches(".*TC \\d{2}.*");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the slash at the begining and the end of your regular expression like that :

```
TC \\d{2}
```

This works for your first exemple. If you want all strings containing TC 10, you need to add some part at the begining and the end like .* (which means 'anything')

The final regular expression should be :

```
.*TC \\d{2}.*
```